# How can I get the average of values based on the range of values from other variable using R?

Tags: r, statistics, mean

For example 
I have two variable R and T

```
T   R
0   0.626290968
0.1 0.447799532
0.2 0.408269444
0.3 0.383617332
0.4 0.364870538
0.5 0.352411299
0.6 0.332493421
0.7 0.328406709
0.8 0.314931307
0.9 0.326861296
1   0.337731233
```

I would like to estimate average of T based on range of 0.3-0.9 in R variable
thanks in advance

Comment: Create a variable with `cut` and use that to group and get the `mean` with `aggregate` or `dplyr` or `data.table`

Answer (score 1):

```
> with(Df, mean(R[T >= 0.3 & T <= 0.9]) )
```

or

```
aggregate(Df$R, list(cut(Df$T, breaks=c(0.3,0.9))), mean)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(T >= .3, T <= .9) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(R))
```